# Proper organization of PHP code for CRUD application?

Tags: php, crud

What is the most efficient way of organizing PHP code for a CRUD application? What are the well-known naming conventions?
I have a class and its getters and setters just seem to be SQL queries. Is this correct, or how am I supposed to organize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at DomainModels and DataMappers. In general, I recommend the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com) and its [Quickstart Tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html), as it [teaches](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html) these two very relevant patterns in a few minutes by example. You do not need to switch to Zend Framework afterwards, but it is good learning material.

Comment: For my opinion Zend strength is not to have good and intuitive naming conventions.

Comment: I differ - the Zend_AutoLoader has a nice way of loading and a clear way of organizing files. But the main question was on the organization and naming is only a small part of it - the main part should go into using the right patterns for maintainability and scalability.

Answer (score 1):

Use the MVC pattern. Then you allready have files in the folders:

```
models
views
controllers
```

inside this folders I would recommend not to use prefixes or sufixes because the files are already in such an folder. But extend all controller files and model files from one main class!

Maybe you want to download and study a example project made in [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org) framework which is [very well structured](http://book.cakephp.org/view/899/CakePHP-Folder-Structure) and uses CRUD as well!